# Positioning of the elements - not in the same line

Tags: android

I have started learning android development and I have stumbled across a thing I don't quite understand why is it happening. Here is the code I am having trouble with:

```
    <LinearLayout
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">

        <LinearLayout
            android:orientation="horizontal"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_weight="1">

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
                android:text="@string/lbl_Title"
                android:id="@+id/lbl_Title"
                android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin" />

            <EditText
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:id="@+id/editText"
                android:layout_weight="2"
                android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin" />
        </LinearLayout>

        <LinearLayout
            android:orientation="horizontal"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_weight="1">

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
                android:text="@string/lbl_Title"
                android:id="@+id/lbl_Date"
                android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin" />

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
                android:text="-"
                android:id="@+id/textView2"
                android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin" />/>
        </LinearLayout>
    </LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

Which results in the following:

[image]

As you can see, even though my two containers are exactly the same, for unknown reason text under the second container is located slightly above the first element. Why is this so?

P.S. These containers are under the `RelativeLayout` panel.

Comment: I dont understand your problem. can you tell me what you want exactly?

Comment: How come the two title labels are not aligned in the same hypothetical row?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is the `EditText`. Since you are only using `wrap_content` on the second `TestView` on the right side, the height of that linear layout is smaller than the one on the left.

Answer (score 1):

I have changed some portions. Now its working as your requirement

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent">

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:gravity="center_vertical">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:gravity="center_vertical"
        android:orientation="horizontal">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/lbl_Title"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Title"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge" />

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/editText"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="2" />
    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:orientation="horizontal">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/lbl_Date"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Title"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textView2"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="-"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge" />/>
    </LinearLayout>
    </LinearLayout>
</RelativeLayout>
```